# Convert MSB first to LSB first

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

I want to convert an unsigned short value from MSB first to LSB first. Did the below code but its not working. Can someone point the error what i did

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  unsigned short value = 0x000A;
  char *m_pCurrent = (char *)&value;
  short temp;
  temp = *(m_pCurrent+1);       
  temp = (temp << 8) | *(unsigned char *)m_pCurrent;
  m_pCurrent += sizeof(short); 
  cout << "temp    " << temp << endl; 
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Actual intention is to keep it in other function, sorry for bat coding style

Comment: "its not working" is not a proper description of the problem. It can mean anything from "it does not compile because of error XYZ" to "It is calculating the first 100 digits of pi, when it was supposed to do something else".

Comment: Do you mean most significant bit or byte?

Comment: What you really want to do? I mean, do you want to transfer binary data between different processors, or it is just an exercise?

Comment: Does `B` refer to bits or bytes?  Code looks like `B` is for bytes but then it is "not working".  Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What was wrong is that you first assigned the `value`'s MSB to the `temp`'s LSB, then shifted it again to MSB and assigned `value`'s LSB to LSB. Basically, you had interchanged `*(m_pCurrent + 1)` and `*m_pCurrent` so the whole thing had no effect.

The simplified code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    unsigned short value = 0x00FF;
    short temp = ((char*) &value)[0];           // assign value's LSB
    temp = (temp << 8) | ((char*) &value)[1];   // shift LSB to MSB and add value's MSB
    cout << "temp    " << temp << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you please also explain the code consicely?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple but slow implementation:

```
#include <cstdint>

const size_t USHORT_BIT = CHAR_BIT * sizeof(unsigned short);

unsigned short ConvertMsbFirstToLsbFirst(const unsigned short input) {
  unsigned short output = 0;
  for (size_t offset = 0; offset < USHORT_BIT; ++offset) {
    output |= ((input >> offset) & 1) << (USHORT_BIT - 1 - offset);
  }
  return output;
}
```

You could easily template this to work with any numeric type.

Comment: `USHORT_BIT` is good for the usual situation where `unsigned short` has no padding bits.  Should  `unsigned short` have padding, a different `USHORT_BIT` calculation is needed.

Comment: In what situations would you say that `unsigned short` is padded?

Comment: The spec detail "For unsigned integer types other than unsigned char, the bits of the object representation shall be divided into two groups: value bits and padding bits (there need not be any of the latter)." In a system that has no native `short` type implemented in hardware, padding of a wider type can be used to implement the `short`.  Still - your bit conversion code is on the right track +1.

Comment: @chux So is it possible for an `unsigned short` to have a number of value bits *other than 16*?

Comment: Certainly `unsigned short` can be > 16 bits.  Still 16 is the most common. It must at _least_ cover the range of 0 to 65535.  Should code need exact 16 bits, use `uint16_t`.   BTW: "possible for an unsigned short to have a number of value bits other than 16?" is a good post-able question.

Comment: @chux In the case that the number of bits in an `unsigned short` is greater than 16, is there a way to determine which of the bits are value bits and which of the bits are padding bits?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81559/discussion-between-chux-and-redrobohood).